# Converting characters to numerical values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df called 'XLK':

```
       Market Cap   PE  
AAN     3.25B      23.6 
AAPL    819.30B    18.44    
ACFN    6.18M      2.1  
ACIW    2.63B      103.15
```

I just want the market cap for values > 100 million, so expected output is:

```
       Market Cap   PE  
AAN     3.25B      23.6 
AAPL    819.30B    18.44    
ACIW    2.63B      103.15
```

I've tried converting the letters to the appropriate 0's with no success:

```
XLK['Market Cap'].replace('M','000000')
XLK.drop[XLK_quote['Market Cap'] < '100M'].index
```

Comment: Will you look at that... an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `replace` with `regex=True` and use replacement strings that emulate scientific notation.  Then use `astype(float)` or `pd.to_numeric`.

```
df[df.Market_Cap.replace(dict(B='E9', M='E6'), regex=True).astype(float) >= 100E6]

     Market_Cap      PE
AAN       3.25B   23.60
AAPL    819.30B   18.44
ACIW      2.63B  103.15
```

---

Equivalently

```
dct = dict(B='E9', M='E6')
num = pd.to_numeric(df.Market_Cap.replace(dct, regex=True), 'coerce')
df[num >= 100E6]
```

Comment: I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: N/A
 .... is there a way to ignore Nan values?

Comment: there are 500 rows in the df, guess theres one thats NA

Comment: I updated the second version using `pd.to_numeric` to include a parameter setting that forces things it can't parse to `np.nan`.  It should work with `NA` now.

Comment: I'm convinced regex is overkill here. Can we do without it?

Comment: w/o regex it brings error: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 3.08B

Comment: One way to find out... you gonna test it... My 3 & 4 year olds have legos they want me to help them build

Comment: w/ the 'coerce' edit it now shows an empty df

Comment: @thomas.mac Whoops, fixed

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, specify a `mapping` and then substitute with `str.map`:

```
In [723]: mapping
Out[723]: {'B': 1000000000, 'K': 1000, 'M': 1000000}

In [724]: df[df['Market Cap'].str[:-1].astype(float) * df['Market Cap'].str[-1].map(mapping) > 100e6]
Out[724]: 
     Market Cap      PE
AAN       3.25B   23.60
AAPL    819.30B   18.44
ACIW      2.63B  103.15
```